# Consumable web service for any device

Tags: c#, web-services

I am developing a project in Layers with C #, and it is required that it has as output a service, to be consumed by different devices. What type of service can be developed so that your operation is optimal in all devices ?. What do you recommend Soap, Web Api or is there any other

Comment: Really depends on what kind of service it is, but I'd go with a Web API, since it's really easy to implement and widely supported.

Comment: The service will be consumed by a website with Angular. But I do not know how complex the reading is from Angular with the Api web

Comment: In this case I'll most definitely would go with an WebApi. Front-End Javascript frameworks like React and Angular "depend" on Web APIs serving them content. A `fetch("url").then(result => /*do stuff */);`, should be all you need for a GET call, even though there are fancier methods out there to do stuff like this, like [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

Comment: Thanks, I will use then the web api for this project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/).

Check my sample code but I consume it by Web Pages:

**Server Side**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/PostMaterialRequest")]        
    public IHttpActionResult PostMaterialRequest(List<ItemDto> items)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var i in items)
            {
                _context.Items.Add(new Item()
                {
                    MaterialId = i.MaterialId,
                    Description = i.Description,
                    Unit = i.Unit,
                    Quantity = i.Quantity,
                    MaterialRequestId = i.MaterialRequestId
                });

                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

**Client-Side**

```
function postItem(materials) {       
        $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/PostMaterialRequest',
            data: JSON.stringify(materials),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("do something with " + data);               
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                console.log('Failed to save.');
            }
        });
    }
```

Sample of [Web API consume by Mobile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/mobile-clients/index)

I hope, I point you to right direction.

Comment: Thanks, I will review the links and information provided